# Sidebar Search parent categories font-weight Bold

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need some help on the sidebar search.

What i try is to have the parent categories font-weight: bold 
the subcategories like there are already font-weight: normal

How to do this?

```
  <?php 
  if(isset($sCategory)) {
    $category = array("pk_i_id" => $sCategory);
  } else {
    if(osc_is_home_page() && osc_is_search_page()){
  $category = 'null';
    } else {$category = array("pk_i_id" => '0');}
  }
  osc_categories_select('sCategory', $category , __('All property types...', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: _"How to do this?"_ - well for sure not by looking at PHP code only ... Check out what the resulting HTML structure is first, and then see what (presumably rather simple) CSS selector(s) can be used to apply the desired formatting.

Comment: Can you explain me more please i'm new in this. Thanks

Comment: No, actually first of all rather you would need to explain more - please go read [ask]. This seems to be a code snippet of some framework, so start with a) telling us which one that is, and b) familiarizing yourself with what its mechanism is for modifying templates/stylesheets. Then go familiarize yourself with your browser's developer tools, they will help you analyze the HTML (well, actually rather DOM) structure in the place in question. Report back when you've done that, and are able to ask a more specific question. (Edit this one, please, don't create a new one.)

Answer (score 0):

i find this in oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hCategories.php

```
/**
* Helper Categories
* @package Osclass
* @subpackage Helpers
* @author Osclass
*/

/**
 * Gets current category
 *
 * @return array
 */
function osc_category() {
    if (View::newInstance()->_exists('subcategories')) {
        $category = View::newInstance()->_current('subcategories');
    } elseif (View::newInstance()->_exists('categories')) {
        $category = View::newInstance()->_current('categories');
    } elseif (View::newInstance()->_exists('category')) {
        $category = View::newInstance()->_get('category');
    } else {
        $category = null;
    }
    return($category);
}

/**
 * Low level function: Gets the list of categories as a tree
 *
 * <code>
 * <?php
 *  $c = osc_get_categories();
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @return <array>
 */
function osc_get_categories() {
   if ( !View::newInstance()->_exists('categories') ) {
       osc_export_categories(Category::newInstance()->toTree());
    }
    return  View::newInstance()->_get('categories');
}

/**
 * Low level function: Gets the value of the category attribute
 *
 * @return <array>
 */
function osc_category_field($field, $locale = '') {
    return osc_field(osc_category(), $field, "");
}

/**
 * Gets the number of categories
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_priv_count_categories() {
    return View::newInstance()->_count('categories');
}

/**
 * Gets the number of subcategories
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_priv_count_subcategories() {
    return View::newInstance()->_count('subcategories');
}

/**
 * Gets the total of categories. If categories are not loaded, this function will load them.
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_count_categories() {
    if ( !View::newInstance()->_exists('categories') ) {
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', Category::newInstance()->toTree() );
    }
    return osc_priv_count_categories();
}

/**
 * Let you know if there are more categories in the list. If categories are not loaded, this function will load them.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function osc_has_categories() {
    if ( !View::newInstance()->_exists('categories') ) {
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', Category::newInstance()->toTree() );
    }
    return View::newInstance()->_next('categories');
}

/**
 * Gets the total of subcategories for the current category. If subcategories are not loaded, this function will load them and
 * it will prepare the the pointer to the first element
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_count_subcategories() {
    $category = View::newInstance()->_current('categories');
    if ( $category == '' ) return -1;
    if ( !isset($category['categories']) ) return 0;
    if ( !is_array($category['categories']) ) return 0;
    if ( count($category['categories']) == 0 ) return 0;
    if ( !View::newInstance()->_exists('subcategories') ) {
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('subcategories', $category['categories']);
    }
    return osc_priv_count_subcategories();
}

/**
 * Let you know if there are more subcategories for the current category in the list. If subcategories are not loaded, this
 * function will load them and it will prepare the pointer to the first element
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function osc_has_subcategories() {
    $category = View::newInstance()->_current('categories');
    if ( $category == '' ) return -1;
    if ( !isset($category['categories']) ) return false;

    if ( !View::newInstance()->_exists('subcategories') ) {
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('subcategories', $category['categories']);
    }
    $ret = View::newInstance()->_next('subcategories');
    //we have to delete for next iteration
    if (!$ret) View::newInstance()->_erase('subcategories');
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Gets the name of the current category
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return string
 */
function osc_category_name($locale = "") {
    if ($locale == "") $locale = osc_current_user_locale();
    return osc_category_field("s_name", $locale);
}

/**
 * Gets the description of the current category
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return string
 */
function osc_category_description($locale = "") {
    if ($locale == "") $locale = osc_current_user_locale();
    return osc_category_field("s_description", $locale);
}

/**
 * Gets the id of the current category
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return string
 */
function osc_category_id($locale = "") {
    if ($locale == "") $locale = osc_current_user_locale();
    return osc_category_field("pk_i_id", $locale);
}

/**
 * Gets the slug of the current category. WARNING: This slug could NOT be used as a valid W3C HTML tag attribute as it could have other characters besides [A-Za-z0-9-_] We only did a urlencode to the variable
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return string
 */
function osc_category_slug($locale = "") {
    if ($locale == "") $locale = osc_current_user_locale();
    return osc_category_field("s_slug", $locale);
}

/**
 * Returns if the category has the prices enabled or not
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function osc_category_price_enabled() {
    return (boolean)osc_category_field("b_price_enabled");
}

/**
 * Returns category's parent id
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_category_parent_id() {
    return osc_category_field("fk_i_parent_id");
}

/**
 * Gets the total items related with the current category
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_category_total_items() {
    return osc_category_field("i_num_items", "");
    //$category = osc_category();
    //return CategoryStats::newInstance()->getNumItems($category);
}

/**
 * Reset the pointer of the array to the first category
 *
 * @return void
 */
function osc_goto_first_category() {
    View::newInstance()->_reset('categories');
}

/**
 * Gets list of non-empty categories
 *
 * @return void
 */
function osc_get_non_empty_categories() {
    $aCategories = Category::newInstance()->toTree(false);
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', $aCategories );
    return  View::newInstance()->_get('categories');
}

/**
 * Prints category select
 *
 * @return void
 */
function osc_categories_select($name = 'sCategory', $category = null, $default_str = null) {
    if($default_str == null) $default_str = __('Select a category');
    CategoryForm::category_select(Category::newInstance()->toTree(), $category, $default_str, $name);
}

/**
 * Get th category by id or slug
 *
 * @since 3.0
 * @param $by two possibilities: slug or id
 * @param $what the id or slug category we're looking for
 * @return array
 */
function osc_get_category($by, $what) {
    if( !in_array($by, array('slug', 'id')) ) {
        return false;
    }

    switch ($by) {
        case 'slug':
            return Category::newInstance()->findBySlug($what);
        break;
        case 'id':
            return Category::newInstance()->findByPrimaryKey($what);
        break;
    }
}

function osc_category_move_to_children() {
    $category = View::newInstance()->_current('categories');
    if ( $category == '' ) return -1;
    if ( !isset($category['categories']) ) return false;

    if(View::newInstance()->_exists('categoryTrail')) {
        $catTrail = View::newInstance()->_get('categoryTrail');
    } else {
        $catTrail = array();
    }
    $catTrail[] = View::newInstance()->_key('categories');
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categoryTrail', $catTrail);
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', $category['categories']);
    View::newInstance()->_reset('categories');
}

function osc_category_move_to_parent() {
    $category = View::newInstance()->_get('categories');
    $category = end($category);

    if ( $category == '' ) return -1;
    if ( !isset($category['fk_i_parent_id']) ) return false;

    $keys = View::newInstance()->_get('categoryTrail');
    $position = array_pop($keys);
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categoryTrail', $keys);
    if(!View::newInstance()->_exists('categories_tree')) {
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories_tree', Category::newInstance()->toTree());
    }
    $scats['categories'] = Category::newInstance()->toTree();
    if(count($keys)>0) {
        foreach($keys as $k) {
            $scats = $scats['categories'][$k];
        }
    }

    $scats = $scats['categories'];

    View::newInstance()->_erase('categories');
    View::newInstance()->_erase('subcategories');
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', $scats);
    View::newInstance()->_seek('categories', $position);
}

/**
 * Gets the total of subcategories for the current category. If subcategories are not loaded, this function will load them and
 * it will prepare the the pointer to the first element
 *
 * @return int
 */
function osc_count_subcategories2() {
    $category = View::newInstance()->_current('categories');
    if ( $category == '' ) return -1;
    if ( !isset($category['categories']) ) return 0;
    if ( !is_array($category['categories']) ) return 0;
    return count($category['categories']);
}

function osc_export_categories($categories = null) {
    if($categories==null) {
        $categories = Category::newInstance()->toTree();
    }
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories', $categories);
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('categories_tree', $categories);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer to solve this problem!

Past it only in sidebar search and change the values!

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  option:nth-child(2), option:nth-child(12), option:nth-child(21), option:nth-child(29), option:nth-child(33), option:nth-child(38), option:nth-child(42), option:nth-child(45){
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```